# How can I "scratch" on dampened strings without "squeaking" on my electric guitar?

Tags: electric-guitar

I love the scratchy sound my acoustic guitar makes when I strum while the left hand damps the strings by lifting a bar chord. However, on my electric, the same technique just makes a silly squeak.

Demonstration with E-shape A minor chord:

- Acoustic (sweet): https://vocaroo.com/i/s0pFacir8W7C
- Electric (squeaky): https://vocaroo.com/i/s187tBSIqMy1

How can I get the same effect on my electric guitar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in the signal chain you've got some reverb going on. Perhaps it's a setting on your amplifier? I think that's what's accentuating the noise. If there's a "depth" or "intensity" control for it, turn it down. Or just turn the reverb off and see if it goes away.

Comment: You're totally right, I forgot about those knobs on my amplifier! I turned the reverb and "T. dynamics" down to zero, and now the squeaks are much less audible! Thank you! https://vocaroo.com/i/s0taRiLorQfw